# UberRUSH delivery state after client Cancel call

Tags: uber-api

I have a question regarding UberRUSH API.

I read https://developer.uber.com/docs/deliveries/references/api/v1/deliveries-delivery_id-cancel-post and it's not clear for me what is the state of delivery right after successful `POST /v1/deliveries/{delivery_id}/cancel`.
I will get just `204` status code in response then, and I don't know if status of delivery will be set to client_canceled during that call, or I will be changed asynchronously and I should wait for status update from Uber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [statuses guide in the developer documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/deliveries/guides/statuses) provides the answer:

> **client_canceled**: This delivery was canceled by the API client. If you want to update the status of a trip to client_canceled, please refer to the POST /deliveries/{delivery_id}/cancel endpoint.